# Android Scolling Large Image horizontal over x3000 pixels

Tags: java, android, imageview

Ive been trying and trying to find a way to deal with large images but with no luck anything over about 3000 pixels is working with the Android Studio Andriod emulator but not on real devices just blank no erros

Ive tried so many different layouts and changing the image format to PNG BMP and Jpeg decreasing the colour Depth but nothing over 3000 works.

the only way I got it working was with the following code this works on any size image but its to slow like really slow!

```
     handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

  Bitmap SOURCE_BITMAP = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.largepic);
  Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(SOURCE_BITMAP, START_X, START_Y, WIDTH_PX, HEIGHT_PX, null, false);
          ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
          image.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
                 START_X = START_X +1;
                 WIDTH_PX = WIDTH_PX+1
      handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
```

Searching Stackoverflow I found answers using Scrollview the following layout but again anything over about 3000x only seems to work on the Android Emulator not real device.

So please if anyone knows for sure a way to do this please help.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: 3000 what? Pixels? IMages?

Comment: Yes over 3000 pixels on the horizontal ill edit my post thanks

Comment: May be an issue with memory

Comment: I never get a out of memory error but most other posts on the subject on stack overflow suggest this -  I did read one post here someone put it worked under BlueStacks but not on real device, So I think this is the problem.

Comment: After more searching on Stackoverflow this time for" ImageView not working on real device" - I put the image in mipmap-xxxhdpi and had some good results ill keep testing....

Comment: Ive had a image upto 5000x working but an image of 10000 didnt work